# OutlinedButton BorderSide is ignored in OutlinedButtonThemeData => Borderside.color and BorderSide.width is always default

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-theme

I am trying to apply a custom buttonStyle inside of ThemeData for my Flutter App.
Everything works fine, but the BorderSide is ignored and is always the default (`BorderSide.color = Colors.black` and `BorderSide.width = 1.0`)

How can I change the BorderSide **inside Theme** so it gets red with a radius of 2.0?

```
outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    shape: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
      return RoundedRectangleBorder(
        // borderRadius is not ignored and gets applied to OutlinedButton => everything fine
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
        // here it gets interesting, the side-parameter is always ignored and defaults to `color: Colors.black` and `width: BorderSide.width = 1.0`
        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2.0),
      );
    }),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same issue, `OutlinedButtonThemeData` has a own `side` parameter. The `BorderSide` has to be applied there.